# A word for paying attention to detail

Tags: word-choice

Looking for a word that describes "Paying attention to the smallest details, though they might not matter".

Starts with the letter "P"

Comment: Perfectionistic?

Comment: If a word starting with *M* is acceptable too, try *meticulous*.

Comment: I think you’re too picky about the “starts with the letter *p”* bit. The most obvious answer is *attentive*.

Comment: Are you doing a crossword or why does it need to start with a P?

Comment: @Em1 maybe alliteration?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**[persnickety](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persnickety)**: giving a lot of attention to details that are minor or not important

Comment: @coneslayer...That's a word I didn't know...learning somethng new everyday :) I'm adopting it for use in the office...

Comment: In British English this is pernickety

Comment: In both American and British English it is an odd and dated word.

Comment: @fredsbend Hardly.  It depends whom you’re dating.

Comment: @fredsbend: Hmm. Google Define loves it, showing it steadily climbing up the usage curve over the past few decades. (http://www.google.com/search?q=persnickety+define)

Comment: @Sz. Damn hipsters.

Answer (score 35):

*Pedantic* is the first word that comes to mind.

According to Oxford Dictionaries, [*pedantic*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pedantic) is someone who is:

> Excessively concerned with minor details or rules, overscrupulous.

Some synonyms beginning with a *"P"* : *perfectionist, punctilious, precisionist*.

Comment: Does that mean that the excessive concern being put is unnecessary? Or, can it be necessary also?

Answer (score 9):

I think that the "p" word you might want is **punctilious.**

> **Punctilious** (*comparative* **more punctilious**, *superlative* **most punctilious**)
>
> 1. Strictly attentive to detail; meticulous or fastidious, particularly to codes or conventions.
>
>    *With a **punctilious** slap of the gloves, the duel was now inevitable.*
> 2. Precise or scrupulous; finicky or nitpicky.
>
> [source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/punctilious)

Comment: It would be helpful to include a dictionary definition so people unfamiliar with the word don't have to google it too see how closely it fits.

Comment: @MartinSmith: OK, fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Consider *[pettifogging](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pettifogging)*, present participle of *[pettifog](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pettifog#English)*, which per wiktionary is to quibble and nitpick over trivial details.  A *[pettifogger](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pettifogger#English)* is  “Someone who quibbles over trivia, and raises petty, annoying objections”.

Comment: Pettyfrogging is the business of busybodies.

Answer (score 5):

*Precisian,* OED sense 2:

> A person who is rigidly precise or punctilious in the observance of rules or forms; a purist, a stickler, a pedant.

*Precise,* OED sense 3.a:

> Strict in the observance of rule, usage, etc.; formal, correct; scrupulous, particular; (occas.) overly formal, fastidious. Also: (of a practice or rule) strictly observed.

Answer (score 4):

*Punctilious* would be my answer if it had to begin with *p*, and was the one that first came to mind. However, I think that *meticulous* is a word that better matches the question.

*Meticulous* is a positive word. *Per(s)nickety* implies being difficult to please more than it does attention to detail, and is also a negative word.

Answer (score 2):

I would add [picky](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Picky):

> - exacting especially about details.
> - excessively meticulous; fussy.

Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 2):

I often use the word ***[particular](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/particular)*** to describe someone who is meticulous or fastidious.

> 1. :  of, relating to, or being a single person or thing
> 2. obsolete :  partial
> 3. **:  of, relating to, or concerned with details**
> 4. a :  distinctive among other examples or cases of the same general category :  notably unusual 
>      b :  being one unit or element among others
> 5. a :  denoting an individual member or subclass in logic
>      b :  affirming or denying a predicate to a part of the subject —used of a proposition in logic <“some men are wise” is a particular affirmative>
> 6. **a :  concerned over or attentive to details :  meticulous 
>
>      b :  nice in taste :  fastidious
>
>      c :  hard to please :  exacting**

This word has the advantage of being much more common over the others mentioned here. I would prefer this to all the others already listed.

Answer (score 1):

"Pedantic" often applies to someone who takes "correctness" to an extreme level, including paying attention to details that don't matter in the grand scheme.

Edit:  Didn't notice that this was previously mentioned so I've improved with a link:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedant

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. Please do read through other answers when adding one. This doesn't add anything to [a previous answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/186044/18696).

Comment: i just learned something about myself with your answer. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for *painstaking*. By itself it doesn't mean "attention to detail", but it is often combined with it to intensify: *painstaking attention to detail*.

Answer (score 0):

The word that came to mind for me was "picayune" which as an adjective means worthless or useless.  So in context the following would answer the OP's question:

> "I don't like to ask Sam to review my designs because he points out picayune grammatical mistakes while missing important conceptual errors."